# Regular expression, replace between "<" and ">", php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I'm very weak in regular expressions.

I simply need to replace `<` and `>`  (and *anything* between) with new content.

This is what I have:

```
$key = preg_replace('/<.*>/', '', $key);
```

`My little string <5>` should simply be `My little string`.
`My little string <96>` should simply be `My little string`.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works if you supply the string instead of `$key`:

```
preg_replace('/<.*>/', '', 'My little string <96>');
```

What is the value of `$key`?

Comment: Wow - I'm not used to be right initially. It turns out that I was searching for something that didn't exist. When I fixed my code that created the string, it worked.

Comment: better to use /<[^>]++>/ instead to avoid problems with consequtive brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`$key` needs to be equal to the string you are tring to replace in. There is nothing wrong with your regular expression.